# When to use "new" constructor in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question about best practice in flutter apps.

When do I need to use the "new" constructor? 
In the code below, both code snippets are working.

Should I use the "new" constructor anyways,
Or only in specific points of the code?

Thank you !!!

```
return new Container(
  margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 16.0
  ),
  alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
  child: new Text("TEST")
);

return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 16.0
  ),
  alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
  child:Text("TEST")
);
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` is optional starting with Dart 2. You should not use it to stay current with the latest. 
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30921
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/20750